# Bash remove forward slash

Tags: bash, macos

In my bash script I have a variable:

```
appPath="/Payload/coolApp.app"
```

I want to create a string containing:

```
"build/ios/coolApp/"
```

I figured I could use bash string replacement operator:

```
${string/substring/replacement}
```

Unfortunately I discovered that it doesn't remove forward slashes inside a substring.

Example script:

```
appPath="/Payload/coolApp.app"

appName=${appPath/"/.app"/}
appName=${appPath/"/Payload"/}

echo "build/ios/$appName/"
```

My output becomes this:

```
build/ios//Payload/coolApp.app/
```

**My Question: Why doesn't it remove the forwards slashes?**
NOTE: I am currently running on MacOSX 10.11.6

Testing solution scripts:

```
#!/bin/sh

appPath="/Payload/coolApp.app"

appName=${appPath/"/.app"/}
appName=${appPath/"/Payload"/}
echo "Original:" "build/ios/$appName/"


appName=${appPath/"\/.app"/}
appName=${appPath/"\/Payload"/}
echo "Escape \:" "build/ios/$appName/"


v1="${appPath/\/Payload/build\ios}"
echo "heemayl:" $v1


v2="${appPath##/Payload/}"
v2="build/ios/${appPath%.app}/"
echo "redneb:" $v2
```

Output:

```
Original: build/ios//Payload/coolApp.app/
Escape \: build/ios//Payload/coolApp.app/
heemayl: build/ios/coolApp.app
redneb: build/ios//Payload/coolApp/
```

Comment: Do you *need* to remove it? Multiple adjacent `/`s are identical to a single `/` except at the very front of a path, and even there it is generally treated the same as one unless the operating system wants to give it a special meaning.

Comment: My intend use to to extract the appName and use it in a bunch of different locations.  The path example felt like the simplest way to so my intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I figured I could use bash string replacement operator:
>
> ```
> ${string/substring/replacement}
> ```
>
> Unfortunately I discovered that it doesn't remove forward slashes
>   inside a substring.

But of course it does, or at least can do.  You simply need to distinguish the slashes that are part of the substitution syntax from those that are part of the data:

```
appPath=/Payload/coolApp.app

echo ${appPath/\/Payload/build/ios}
```

Note in particular that only the first slash or double slash and the second slash are significant to the substitution syntax.  Any subsequent slashes, such as the one between "build" and "ios" in the example, are just data.

Furthermore, you are getting a bit tripped up by quotation.  This form will output what you want, too:

```
echo ${appPath/\/Payload/build\/ios}
```

but this will not:

```
echo "${appPath/\/Payload/build\/ios}"
```

That's because the second backslash in the substitution is also just data, so the substitution produces `build/ios\/coolApp/`.  When that appears *outside* double quotes, the backslash is treated as a quote character to be removed during the subsequent quote-removal step.  When it appears *inside* double quotes, it is itself a quote character only when followed by a character that needs escaping in that context (`$`, `, `"`, or `\`), or by a newline.  In your case, therefore, it is just data, so it is not removed during the quote removal phase of command-line expansion.

More generally, you are using quotes in a lot of places where you do not need to do.  Unlike many languages, the shell language does not rely on quotation to distinguish strings from other syntactic elements.  In fact, it has very little distinction of that kind.  You need to use quotation only to suppress what would otherwise be a special meaning of one or more characters.

Answer (score 3):

Using `BASH_REMATCH` can come in handy for this type of scenario:

```
appPath="/Payload/coolApp.app"
pattern='/.*/(.*)[.].*'

[[ $appPath =~ $pattern ]] && echo "build/ios/${BASH_REMATCH[1]}/"
```

**Output:**

```
build/ios/coolApp/
```

The double bracket statement `[[ $appPath =~ $pattern ]]` acts as an `IF` statement, which essentially asks itself "does `$appPath` fit the `$pattern`?" — if it does then echo the substitution.

Here's a summary of what the regex pattern does:

> `/.*/` matches `/Payload/`

```
  / matches the character / literally
  .* matches any character (except newline)
   |_ Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times
    / matches the character / literally
```

> `(.*)` matches `coolApp` and captures it to `BASH_REMATCH[1]` ( *capture group 1* )

```
  1st Capturing group (.*)
  .* matches any character (except newline)
   |_ Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times
```

> `[.].*` matches `.app` and anything else to the end of line

```
  [.] match a single character ( character class )
   |_ . the literal character .
      .* matches any character (except newline)
       |_ Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times
```

It may seem complicated, although once you understand what the pattern is doing it starts to make sense. Being able to visualize the pattern within a [regex editor](https://regex101.com/r/iG2iI3/1) is often helpful for learning also.

Comment: I'd suggest single quotes rather than double quotes for the pattern -- that way there's no question that backslashes, if present, are literal.

Comment: I'd also strongly suggest `[.]` rather than `\.` for improved ambiguity (in making it completely obvious to a reader, without needing to look at the quoting type or context, that you're creating a character class, not performing string-escaping at assignment time).

Comment: This is a bit beyond me at the moment, given that my regex experience is next to n00b level.  I will have to research this some more.

Comment: @Charles, Thanks very much for the suggestion it makes sense, although I was a bit confused about the single quotes comment, but I presume you mean that the escaping isn't necessary, and the single quotes reiterates that.

Comment: @l'L'l, ...so, sometimes a backslash has semantic meaning in double-quotes (for instance, in `\$`), but it *never* has semantic meaning in single quotes (other than the entirely-different `$''` quoting style). Less for a reader to think about if a constant string containing backslashes is single-quoted.

Comment: BTW, looks to me like this would be simpler as `[[ $appPath =~ $pattern ]] && echo "build/ios/${BASH_REMATCH[1]}/"`

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape `/` in the string with `\`:

```
$ appPath="/Payload/coolApp.app"

$ echo "${appPath/\/Payload/build\/ios}"
build/ios/coolApp.app
```

Comment: Good to know about escaping.  Using your example and trying to escape still doesn't generate the output I am wanting.

Comment: @mgChristopher As you can see, its working perfectly for me.

Comment: when I run with that I get the following `build\/ios/coolApp.app` not `build/ios/coolApp.app`.

Comment: @mgChristopher So try `${appPath/\/Payload/build/ios}`

Comment: Updating this to the correction, does generate the same output you have listed.  The thing that confuses me is that if I escape the forward slash using the string replacement operator, it doesn't do what I expected.  You can see that example in my update to the Test Solution Script section.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to get replacement to work:

```
a='/Payload/coolApp.app'

echo "simple: ${a///Payload/build/ios}"
echo "plain : ${a//'/Payload'/build/ios}"
echo "front : ${a/#'/Payload'/build/ios}"
echo "end   : build/ios/${a##*/}"
```

When executed they will print:

```
simple: build/ios/coolApp.app
plain : build/ios/coolApp.app
front : build/ios/coolApp.app
end   : build/ios/coolApp.app
```

The simple option just gives as many `/` as the parameter expansion needs.
But it is confusing.

The plain option does almost the same, but quotes the pattern, which makes it a lot more readable.

The front option use an `#` (front of string) to end the need for `/`.

The end option is not a replacement, but a "Remove matching prefix pattern".
It removes everything up to the last `/`. Then, the needed text is prepended.

---

But a more useful way to write this is using variables:

```
a='/Payload/coolApp.app'

b='/Payload/'
c='build/ios/'

a=${a/"$b"/$c}"
echo "var   : ${a}"
```

Which will print:

```
var   : build/ios/coolApp.app
```

Use the variables to make repeated changes:

```
b='/Payload/' c='build/ios/'
a=${a/"$b"/$c}
echo "var1  : ${a}"

b='.app' c='/'
a=${a/"$b"/$c}
echo "var2  : ${a}"
```

Which will print:

```
var1  : build/ios/coolApp.app
var2  : build/ios/coolApp/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
appPath="/Payload/coolApp.app"
appPath="${appPath##/Payload/}"
appPath="build/ios/${appPath%.app}/"
echo "$appPath"
```

it prints:

```
build/ios/coolApp/
```

Comment: I get the following output when running your example `build/ios//Payload/coolApp/`

Comment: @mgChristopher Are you sure? I've verified in multiple machines that it works. Do you run bash?

Comment: I have updated my original question to show the examples in this listing.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the app name, use

```
appName=${appPath##*/}  # Drop everything up to and including the final /
appName=${appName%.app} # Drop the extension
```