# Keeping forward slash in bash $argument for a directory name in MacOSX

Tags: bash, macos, directory, arguments, slash

In MacOSX it is possible to create a folder in Finder that contains a forward slash "/" in the name.

I am trying to bash script the same by doing something similar to

```
args=("$@")
name=${args[0]}
street_corner=${args[1]}
my_folder="Hello ${name} - ${streetcorner}"
mk () {
  case "$1" in /*) :;; *) set -- "./$1";; esac
  mkdir -p "$1"
}
mk $my_folder
```

where street corner is a crossing in the format "street 1/street 2" and thus needs the slash to be kept in the directory name.

I read [several articles like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39646508/bash-remove-forward-slash) where they explain how to manipulate the string to escape or keep the forward when you set the string yourself. The problem I have is that the user passes the argument to be used in the script and therefore the string is already encapsulated when i run the command to the make a directory with **$my_folder** as argument.

How do I expand the value of street_corner without letting the forward slash create a subdirectory named "street 2" located inside the directory "street 1" but instead creating a single directory called "street 1/street 2"?

I have tried these fixes and failed

```
street_corner="${args[0]}"
my_folder='"Hello ${name} - ${streetcorner}"'
my_folder="'Hello ${name} - ${streetcorner}'"
my_folder="Hello ${name} - ${'streetcorner'}"
my_folder="Hello ${name} - ${$"streetcorner"}"
my_folder="Hello "${name}" - "${streetcorner}
```

And also tried to give the input for street_corner like

```
./my_script.sh "name" "street 1\/street 2"
./my_script.sh "name" 'street 1/street 2'
./my_script.sh "name" "'street 1/street 2'"
```

Answer (score 5):

Path names involving `/` and `:` (for reasons to be discussed below) are a bit confusing under macOS. The short answer is:

- You cannot use `/` in a file name.
- For historical reasons, the Finder pretends that you can
- Also for historical reasons, the Finder pretends that you cannot use `:`.

---

First, `/` is not a valid character in a POSIX path name; it is reserved as the path component separator. Command line tools that expect valid file names as arguments will reject those containing `/`.

The Finder *appears* to let you create a file or folder whose name contains a `/`, but it silently converts the `/` to a `:`. You can confirm this from the terminal. Create a folder named `foo/bar` in your home directory; it will appear as `foo:bar` if you run `ls` from the terminal.

---

Second, `:` was historically used as the path separator in classic Mac OS. The Finder still does not allow you to create a folder whose name contains a `:`, but command line tools (like `mkdir`) do. `mkdir foo:bar` will work, and further the name will appear as `foo/bar` in the Finder.

Comment: Therefore, you need to convert slashes in streetcorner to colons in the filename. This should work: `my_folder="Hello ${name} - ${streetcorner//\//:}". You can read that mess in curly braces as: the value of the streetcorner variable (`streetcorner`) with all occurrences of (`//`) a slash character (`\/` - note that it's escaped so it won't be mistaken for a delimiter) replaced with (`/`) colons (`:`).

Comment: Thanks for that @chepner and @gordon-davisson! =)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is not one of quoting.

The forward slash is the path separator in UNIX-type operating systems.  It is pretty much the only character you cannot have in a file name (although it can be part of the path, where it allows the directory hierarchy to be expressed).  You can have spaces, tabs, even newlines.  But no forward slashes.

So the answer is, you cannot use `street1/street2` as a filename without `street1` being interpreted as anything other than a directory.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the script, you need to double quote the right hand side of the lines:

```
name="${args[0]}"
street_corner="${args[1]}"
```

and the command:

```
mk "$my_folder"
```

Also there is a typo.  Remove the underscore from street_corner.

Then call the script like this:

```
./my_script.sh "name" "street 1\/street 2"
```

or

```
./my_script.sh "name" 'street 1/street 2'
```